# How to parse JSON in an embedded v8?

Tags: c++, json, v8

I am trying to Parse JS in my embedded V8 application and I get a SIGSEGV always. I am not sure what is happening.

My code to parse json,

```
v8::Handle<v8::Value> FromJSONString(
    v8::Handle<v8::Value> json_string) {
  v8::HandleScope scope;
  v8::Handle<v8::Context> context = v8::Context::GetCurrent();
  v8::Handle<v8::Object> global = context->Global();

  v8::Handle<v8::Value> JSON_value = global->Get(v8::String::New("JSON"));
  if (!IsObject(JSON_value)) {
    return scope.Close(v8::Undefined());
  }
  v8::Handle<v8::Object> JSON  = JSON_value->ToObject();

  v8::Handle<v8::Value> JSON_parse_value = JSON->Get(v8::String::New("parse"));

  if (JSON_parse_value.IsEmpty() || JSON_parse_value->IsNull() ||
      JSON_parse_value->IsUndefined() ||!JSON_parse_value->IsFunction()) {
    return scope.Close(v8::Undefined());
  }


  v8::Handle<v8::Function> JSON_parse =
      v8::Handle<v8::Function>::Cast(JSON_parse_value);

  return scope.Close(JSON_parse->Call(JSON, 1, &json_string));
}
```

The specific site which crashes =>

```
bool extractSource(std::string* source, std::string& body) {
    v8::HandleScope scope; // this is needed and clears the memory
    if (body.empty()) {
        return false;
    }
    v8::Handle<v8::Value> value = v8_server_utils::FromJSONString(body);
    if (value->IsEmpty()) { // CRASHES HERE.
        return false;
    }
    if (value->IsNull()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (value->IsUndefined()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!value->IsObject()) {
        return false;
    }
    auto object = value->ToObject();
    auto source_key = v8::String::New("source");
    if (object.IsEmpty() || object->IsNull() || object->IsUndefined() ||
        !object->Has(source_key)) {
        return false;
    }
    auto source_obj = object->Get(source_key);
    *source = v8_server_utils::JSStringToCString(source_obj->ToString());
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use JSON Parse function exposed through API:

```
v8::Local<v8::String> str; // some string
v8::Local<v8::Value> result = v8::JSON::Parse(str);
```

Newer versions of V8 provide `EscapableHandleScope` you need to use to return handle from function:

```
v8::EscapableHandleScope scope(isolate);
return scope.Escape(value);
```

This

```
if (value->IsEmpty()) { // CRASHES HERE.
```

should probably be

```
if (value.IsEmpty())
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: v8::JSON does not exist in v3.14.5.

Answer (score 3):

The following code should work provided that you're on an older V8 version, such as v3.14:

```
v8::Handle<v8::Value> FromJsonString (v8::Handle<v8::Value> jsonString) {
  v8::HandleScope scope;
  v8::Handle<v8::Context> context = v8::Context::GetCurrent();
  v8::Handle<v8::Object> global = context->Global();

  // find JSON object in global scope
  v8::Handle<v8::Value> jsonValue = global->Get(v8::String::New("JSON"));

  if (! jsonValue->IsObject()) {
    return scope.Close(v8::Undefined());
  }

  v8::Handle<v8::Object> json = jsonValue->ToObject();

  // find "parse" attribute
  v8::Handle<v8::Value> parse = json->Get(v8::String::New("parse"));

  if (parse.IsEmpty() ||
      ! parse->IsFunction()) {
    return scope.Close(v8::Undefined());
  }

  // cast into a function    
  v8::Handle<v8::Function> parseFunction = v8::Handle<v8::Function>::Cast(parse);

  // and call it
  return scope.Close(parseFunction->Call(json, 1, &jsonString));
}


static bool ExtractSource (std::string& source, std::string const& body) {
  v8::HandleScope scope;

  // convert whole body from cstring to V8 string
  v8::Handle<v8::String> bodyString = v8::String::New(body.c_str(), body.size());

  // call JSON.parse() on the body
  v8::Handle<v8::Value> value = FromJsonString(bodyString);

  // check if result is valid
  if (value.IsEmpty() ||
      value->IsNull() ||
      value->IsUndefined() ||
      ! value->IsObject()) {
    return false;
  }

  auto object = value->ToObject();

  // extract "source" attribute from result     
  auto sourceKey = v8::String::New("source");

  if (object.IsEmpty() || 
      object->IsNull() || 
      object->IsUndefined() ||
      ! object->Has(sourceKey)) {
    return false;
  }

  auto sourceValue = object->Get(sourceKey);

  if (! sourceValue->IsString()) {
    return false;
  }

  // convert the v8 string value into a cstring
  v8::String::Utf8Value sourceString(sourceValue->ToString());

  if (*sourceString == nullptr) {
    return false;
  }

  source.assign(*sourceString, sourceString.length());
  return true;
}

int main () {
  // test data
  std::string body = "{ \"body\": \"test\", \"source\": \"some string value\" }";
  // result
  std::string source;

  // call function and dump result
  std::cout << "is valid: " << ExtractSource(source, body) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "value of source: '" << source << "'" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: at some point the V8 API complete changed. For example, all `New()` methods and `v8::HandleScope`s now require a `v8::Isolate` instance. My solution was for older V8 versions, such as 3.14. If you're unsure what part of the code does not work in newer versions, try compiling it with a newer V8 version, and you'll see tons of errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a native node module and using *NAN* so that it will be supported across all major versions of *Node.js*, then I recommend that you try using the [native-json](http://www.npmjs.com/package/native-json) npm package.

The package exposes the following methods:

```
static Nan::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> Native::JSON::Parse(v8::Local<v8::String> jsonString);

static Nan::MaybeLocal<v8::String> Native::JSON::Stringify(v8::Local<v8::Object> jsonObject, v8::Local<v8::String> gap = v8::Local<v8::String>())
```

As for the changes in `v8::JSON` in the versions of node supported by *NAN*:

`v8::JSON::Parse` was first available in node version 0.12.x - it is *not* otherwise available in versions 0.8 or 0.10.x

`v8::JSON::Stringify` was first available in node version 7 - it is *not* otherwise available in earlier versions

The `native-json` package's `Native::JSON` singleton class will perform the requests in the most efficient way available depending on the version of *Node.js* being built against. If the method is available in that version of *V8* then it will be called.  Otherwise, the `Native::JSON` singleton class falls back to grabbing the `JSON` object from the global context.

Source code is available on the github repository: [node-native-json](http://github.com/mkrufky/node-native-json)

Here is an example of how to use `Native::JSON::Parse`:

```
v8::Local<v8::String> json_string = Nan::New("{ \"JSON\": \"object\" }").ToLocalChecked();

v8::Local<v8::Value> val = Native::JSON::Parse(json_string).ToLocalChecked();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this additional answer because my prior answer is still correct, but as of now a newer and better answer is available.

*NAN* version 2.6.2 was released on April 12, 2017.  This version introduces a new object, `Nan::JSON`

The `Nan::JSON` object provides c++ versions of the methods offered by the `JSON` object in javascript, in a way that is backwards compatible with all versions of Node.js supported by *NAN*. V8 otherwise exposes these methods via the `v8::JSON` object.

#### Nan::JSON.Parse

A simple wrapper around [`v8::JSON::Parse`](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-7.4/da/d6f/classv8_1_1_j_s_o_n.html#a936310d2540fb630ed37d3ee3ffe4504).

Definition:

`Nan::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> Nan::JSON::Parse(v8::Local<v8::String> json_string);`

Use `JSON.Parse(json_string)` to parse a string into a `v8::Value`.

Example:

```cpp
v8::Local<v8::String> json_string = Nan::New("{ \"JSON\": \"object\" }").ToLocalChecked();

Nan::JSON NanJSON;
Nan::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> result = NanJSON.Parse(json_string);
if (!result.IsEmpty()) {
  v8::Local<v8::Value> val = result.ToLocalChecked();
}
```

#### Nan::JSON.Stringify

A simple wrapper around [`v8::JSON::Stringify`](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-7.4/da/d6f/classv8_1_1_j_s_o_n.html#a44b255c3531489ce43f6110209138860).

Definition:

`Nan::MaybeLocal<v8::String> Nan::JSON::Stringify(v8::Local<v8::Object> json_object, v8::Local<v8::String> gap = v8::Local<v8::String>());`

Use `JSON.Stringify(value)` to stringify a `v8::Object`.

Example:

```cpp
v8::Local<v8::Object> obj = Nan::To<v8::Object>(val).ToLocalChecked();

Nan::JSON NanJSON;
Nan::MaybeLocal<v8::String> result = NanJSON.Stringify(obj);
if (!result.IsEmpty()) {
  v8::Local<v8::String> stringified = result.ToLocalChecked();
}
```

Refer to the `V8 JSON` object in the [V8 documentation](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-7.4/da/d6f/classv8_1_1_j_s_o_n.html) for more information about the original `V8` versions these methods and their arguments.

The above was paraphrased from the [*NAN* documentation](https://github.com/nodejs/nan/edit/master/doc/json.md)